# Is it possible to put XCTAsserts inside a loop?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

I'm learning about unit testing and XCode's XCTAssert statements.

I have a situation where I want to test a bunch of things in a sequence, in a dynamic way according to how the environment is set up.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
for (i = 1, etc...) {
     [thisObject doSomethingWith: i];
     thatVariable+=i;
     XCTAssert ([someComparison basedOn:i], @"Fail text customized to %i", i);
};
```

...it doesn't work. The test just passes without even seeming to evaluate the XCTAssert statement.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `XCTAssert` almost anywhere, which including for/while loop.

I think you need to check the for loop is actually doing what you expected. You can add `NSLog` inside the loop to log the value of `i` and other variables.